# How to setState and call another function on a button press in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got a floating action button that opens a sliding panel cart. I want to hide the button when the cart panel is open and show the button when the cart panel is closed. I'm using a visibility widget with the visibility boolean set to whether or not the panel is open.

```
floatingActionButton:
  Visibility(
    child: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        //show cart as a slide up panel
        setState(() {
         isCartButtonVisible = pc.isPanelClosed; //returns true if panel is closed
         });
         pc.show(); //opens cart panel
         },
          child: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket),
  ),
  visible: isCartButtonVisible,
),
```

The problem is that pc.show() doesn't get executed. Is there any way to have a setState on a button press and call another function as well? Any help would be really appreciated.

### Edit

This is the code for pc.show(), it's a built-in method for the panel controller

```
import 'package:sliding_up_panel/sliding_up_panel.dart';
//controls checkout panel
PanelController pc = new PanelController();
```

Comment: pc.show() must get called, may be inner functionality is not workig

Comment: pc.show() gets called if I remove setState(), but then the button doesn't get hidden. In other words, only one thing works, either the panel is shown but the button remains, or the button is hidden but the panel isn't shown. In short, pc.show() definitely works

Comment: Can you please provide the code for pc.show()?

Comment: It's a built in method for the panel controller that controls the panel, I'll add it